Django Nginx And Gunicorn subdomain hosting gets 400 error
Nginx and Django Setup Results in Bad Request (400) Error
I'm trying to configure Nginx to serve my Django application, but I'm encountering a "Bad Request (400)" error. I've set up my Nginx server block and Django settings as follows:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.domain.com;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/diagrjxt/medinote/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/diagrjxt/medinote/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/medinote.sock;
    }
}

DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
Issue:
I've restarted both Gunicorn and Nginx, but I still receive a "Bad Request (400)" error when I try to access the site. There are no errors in the Nginx error log, but the access log shows the following entries:
103.121.239.95 - - [31/Jul/2024:06:22:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/5127.36" "-"
103.119.239.95 - - [31/Jul/2024:06:22:40 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "http://medinote.diagnotech-ai.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"


Please provide your django settings

Django which part of settings?

Try to update the ALLOWED_HOSTS in your Django settings. You provided DEBUG = False ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] which should include your domain name or IP address that you're using to access your site. Using * is not really recommended. Replace it with your actual domain name or IP address and see if it works.
Let me know for further scrutiny.

I have tried ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['subdomain.domain.com'] but still its same mainly its occuring on subdomain but domain is running perfectly

Try adding the IP instead

My subdomain Gunicorn was incorrectly pointing to the main domain's Gunicorn despite the two Gunicorn files having different names. After reinstalling the entire server and reinstalling both Nginx and Gunicorn, everything ran perfectly.

Perfect brother, glad to help!
